# How can I integrate my Python based OpenCV project in Android?

Tags: android, python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on my OpenCV project with Python which basically recognizes hand gestures. I want to do the same using Android. Is it possible? Is there any way to do so?

I want to recognize very basic hand gestures using my Android device. Is it possible with Python & OpenCV with Android? Also share any other way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process can be done via NDK & OpenCV with Java support in Android Studio.
You need to compile NDK libraries and generate .so files. Then the project will work.